# Help fixing stitched panorama

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I took a fisheye picture using my Android phone using the [Google Camera app](https://support.google.com/googlecamera/answer/2840225?hl=en).  Everything turned out pretty good or at least it was quite easy to fix up, except for one section.

I am trying to make this area of the horizon blend a bit better and looking for advice using Photoshop CC to be able to do it.

[image: Horizon]

This picture is zoomed in a fair bit so it doesn't have to be perfect, but it is noticeable at 100%

[image]

I'ved tried to use Content Aware Fill and the Spot healing brush but they seem to just push the line further down the image.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did it by yourself or using **Photomerge**?
Photomerge is very effective sewing.

- Selecting the area at the right part of the sea > make a **New Layer Via Copy** > Distort
- Fix the edge using the **Stamp Tool**, soft to fix the sea, medium-soft to fix the horizon*

[image: fixing]

**Result**

[image: sea]

*Sorry about the gif quality, the best I could do with 2MB limit size.

Comment: Nice answer, but we have to remember about the water part, there are also an imperfect parts. I think the soft Stamp Tool will do the job in a seconds.

Comment: Yes, the main part it's done, following with the same tool the OP can do the rest. The question remark this: –This picture is zoomed in a fair bit so it doesn't have to be perfect–.